# Defining a threshold for results in lsoda, R language

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I have a problem with lsoda in deSolve package in R. (It might be applicable to ode function too). I am modeling the dynamics of a food web using a set of ODEs calculating abundances of 5 species in two identical food webs which are connected through dispersal.
the abundances are calculated in 2000 time steps, and they are not supposed to be negative or less than 1e-6. In that case the result should be changed into 0. I could not find any parameter for lsoda to turn negative results into zero. I tried the following trick in my ODE function:
    solve.model <- function(t,y, parms){

```
solve.model <- function(t,y, parms){

    y <- ifelse(y<1e-6, 0, y)
    #ODE functions here
    #...
    #...
    return(list(dy))
}
```

but it seems not working. Below is a sample of abundances of species in a web. 
[image: abundances of the 5 species in 2000 time steps]

I will be very grateful for your help, and hope the sample code can give enough information about my problem.
Babak

P.S. I am solving the following ODE set for the abundances of species(the first two equations) and resource change (third equation)
[image]

the corresponding code for the function is as below

```
solve.model <- function(t, y, parms){

    y <- ifelse(y<1e-6, 0, y)
    with(parms,{
        # return from vector form into matrix form for calculations
        (R <- as.matrix(y[(max(no.species)*length(no.species)+1):length(y)]))
        (N <- matrix(y[1:(max(no.species)*length(no.species))], ncol=length(no.species)))

        dy1 <- matrix(nrow=max(no.species), ncol=length(no.species))
        dy2 <- matrix(nrow=length(no.species), ncol=1)


        for (i in 1:no.webs){
            species <- no.species[i]
            (abundance <- N[1:species,i])

            adj <- as.matrix(webs[[i]])
            a.temp <- a[1:species, 1:species]*adj
            b.temp <- b[1:species, 1:species]*adj
            h.temp <- h[1:species, 1:species]*adj

            #Calculating sigmas in denominator of Holing type II functional response
            (sum.over.preys <- abundance%*%(a.temp*h.temp))
            (sum.over.predators <- (a.temp*h.temp)%*%abundance)



            #Calculating growth of basal
            (basal.growth <- basals[,i]*N[,i]*(mu*R[i]/(K+R[i])-m))

            # Calculating growth for non-basal species
            no.basal <- rep(1,len=species)-basals[1:species]
            predator.growth<- rep(0, max(no.species))
            (predator.growth[1:species] <- ((abundance%*%(a.temp*b.temp))/(1+sum.over.preys)-m*no.basal)*abundance)

            predation <- rep(0, max(no.species))
            (predation[1:species] <- (((a.temp*b.temp)%*%abundance)/t(1+sum.over.preys))*abundance)

            (pop <- basal.growth + predator.growth - predation)

            dy1[,i] <- pop
            dy2[i] <- 0.0005 #Change in the resource
        }

        #Calculating dispersals .they can be easily replaced
        # by adjacency maps of connections between food webs arbitrarily!

        # added to solve the problem of negative abundances
        deltas <- append(c(dy1), dy2)
        return(list(append(c(dy1),dy2)))    
    })
}
```

this function is used by lsoda by the following call:

```
temp.abund[[j]] <- lsoda(y=initials, func=solve.model, times=0:max.time, parms=parms)
```

Comment: what is your full code?

Comment: I just edited the question. added the code for ODE function and the ODE formulation. Thanks